# CakePHP - multiple filters using HABTM

Tags: cakephp, filtering, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following models: Property and Characteristic

They have a HABTM relationship.

I want to build a query that can take an arbitrary number of characteristic_ids and search for properties that have characteristic x AND characteristic Y AND characteristic Z etc.

At the moment I can only manage an IN() which is the equivalent of the above using OR.

Even a pointer of how the raw SQL to do this would look would be useful as I can convert it to a CakePHP find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create the following method inside your Property model :

```
function getProperties($characteristicsIDs) {
    $ids = $this->characteristicsProperty->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('property_id', 'property_id'),
        'conditions' => array('characteristic_id' => $characteristicsIDs),
        'group' => 'property_id having count(*) = '.count($characteristicsIDs),
    ));

    $ids = array_keys($ids);

    return $ids;
}
```

Then inside you controller :

```
$ids = $this->Property->getProperties($propertiesIDs);
$this->Property->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
    'Property.id' => $ids
    )
));
```

Comment: @wiseguysonly You can then validate the answer.